# Django Channels Push live database updates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-channels

I have a database table displayed on the HTML page but the database is continually updated. I wish to display these updates in real-time with django channels.

I have already written a receiver function with django signals.

My question is: what django channels code should I write in the receiver function, to update the database table on the HTML page to show the changes in real time?

For example, when I visit the HTML page, I would be greeted with a database table. I should see the table updated live, every time there are any changes to the database. Is it possible to do that with the group_send method:

```
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("chat", {"type": "chat.message", "text": "updated queryset"})
```

But instead of sending text, could it send a queryset that is drawn from the database table?

Or is this not the best way to show live updates of a database?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When the table is updated,You can wrap add or uddate data in to json, send it to group user.